# R vectorization implementation in a function

Tags: r, performance, function, vectorization, large-data

I am having trouble to understand how to take advantages of R vectorization to do what I wanted in a more efficient way.

Briefly, for each line, I want to compare the 2nd column ($start) of current line with $start of the previous and next line (all values are integers, let's call these values prev_dist and next_dist). Next, print the 4th column ($condition) of the current line followed by 5 previous $condition or 5 next $condition, depending on which one lower distance value (i.e. $start of previous or next line closest to current line's $start).

```
weather    146   17   Rainy 
weather    147   17   Rainy 
weather    163   16   Sunny 
weather    173   15   Sunny 
weather    176   15   Rainy   
weather    197   12   Rainy
```

I want my output to be something like (in a dataframe):

```
Rainy Rainy Sunny Sunny Sunny Rainy
Rainy Sunny Sunny Sunny Rainy Rainy
etc.
```

I have tried to write a function below, but this function runs forever for a large, simulated datasets.

Could someone help me to understand how to implement vectorization in this case?

```
buildMatrix <- function(input){
 len <- nrow(input)-6
 sequence_matrix <- data.frame()

 for(line in 6:len){

   start <- input[line,]$start
   prev_start <- input[line-1,]$start
   next_start <- input[line+1,]$start
   prev_dist <- abs(start-prev_start)
   next_dist <- abs(start-next_start)
   current_seq <- input[line,]$condition

   if(prev_dist < next_dist || prev_dist == next_dist){
     for(i in 1:5){
       prev_seq <- input[line-i,]$condition
       current_seq <- c(current_seq, prev_seq)}
   } else if(prev_dist > next_dist){
     for(i in 1:5){
       next_seq <- input[line+i,]$condition
       current_seq <- c(current_seq, next_seq)}
   }
   sequence_matrix <- rbind(sequence_matrix, current_seq)
  }
 colnames(sequence_matrix) <- c("p0", "p1", "p2", "p3", "p4", "p5")
 sequence_matrix
}
```

Modified codes:

```
library(dplyr)
islessthan <- abs(df$V2-lead(df$V2)) < abs(df$V2-lag(df$V2))

ans <- lapply(seq_along(islessthan), function(i) if (is.na(islessthan[i])) {
   NA
} else if(islessthan[i]==FALSE) {
c(df$V4[i], head(lag(df$V4, pmax(6-i, 0)), 5))
} else {
c(df$V4[i], head(lead(df$V4, i), 5))
})
```

Comment: Rather than `$V2`, etc. -- why not give informative names to the columns? After doing that, you can create new columns for `prev_start` and `next_start` (padded with `NA` in the last or final row as the case may be). This can be done in 1-line, loop-free statements. Once you get to that stage, the problem will be much easier.

Comment: Point's taken about the naming. Did you mean something like the modified codes above for the columns (I edited my question)?

Comment: What I had in mind is something like `df$prev_start <- c(NA,head(df$start,-1))` and `df$next_start <- c(tail(df$start,-1),NA)`, although `dplyr`-based solutions are probably preferable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `dplyr::lead/lag`functions to your advantage

Your data

```
df <- read.table(text="weather    146   17   Rainy 
weather    147   17   Rainy 
weather    163   16   Sunny 
weather    173   15   Sunny 
weather    176   15   Rainy   
weather    197   12   Rainy", header=FALSE, stringsAsFactors=F)
```

Determine whether each row (0-row) has `+1-row < -1-row`

```
library(dplyr)
islessthan <- lead(df$V2) < lag(df$V2)
# [1]    NA FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE    NA
```

Use `lapply` to iterate through the logical vector created above and your data frame. Rows where `is.na(row) == TRUE` will return `NA`; rows where `islessthan == FALSE` will return the `0-row + +5-rows of column V4`; and rows where `islessthan == TRUE` will return the `-5-rows of column V4 + 0-row`

```
ans <- lapply(seq_along(islessthan), function(i) if (is.na(islessthan[i])) {
                                    NA
                                } else if(islessthan[i]==FALSE) { 
                                    c(df$V4[i], head(lead(df$V4, i), 6))
                                } else { 
                                    c(head(lag(df$V4, 6-i), 6))
                                })
```

Output

```
# [[1]]
# [1] NA

# [[2]]
# [1] "Rainy" "Sunny" "Sunny" "Rainy" "Rainy" NA      NA     

# [[3]]
# [1] "Sunny" "Sunny" "Rainy" "Rainy" NA      NA      NA     

# [[4]]
# [1] "Sunny" "Rainy" "Rainy" NA      NA      NA      NA     

# [[5]]
# [1] "Rainy" "Rainy" NA      NA      NA      NA      NA     

# [[6]]
# [1] NA
```

Note that you haven't specified how to deal with the edge cases (row-1, and row-N), and your example does not have enough observations to return a full vector, thus, `NA`s are present in the output as filler.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I was wondering about one thing, does that function of dplyr still preserve the order of the lines or it's order-agnostic?

Comment: The short answer is it will preserve the order. `dplyr::lead` will advance values in your data by `N`, such that index N will become index 1. `dplyr::lag` will do the opposite.

Comment: I modified my codes according to what I wanted (the comparison of differences of $V2s instead of just $V2 comparison):

`islessthan <- abs(df$V2-lead(df$V2)) < abs(df$V2-lag(df$V2))

ans <- lapply(seq_along(islessthan), function(i) if (is.na(islessthan[i]) || any(is.na(islessthan[i:i-6])) || any(is.na(islessthan[i:i+6]))) {
  NA
} else if(islessthan[i]==FALSE) {
  c(df$V4[i], head(lead(df$V4, i), 6))
} else {
  c(head(lag(df$V4, 6-i), 6))
})`

and the reason I changed the first if statement is this error: Error in lag(df$V4, 6 - i) : n must be a single positive integer.

Comment: However, the error above still persist. Could you please point me where to fix the code?

Comment: Replace `lag(df$V4, 6-i)` with `lag(df$V4, pmax(6-i, 0))` and see if it works

Comment: The error is gone, but I'm not sure what pmax is doing in this case, as the results now has changed (previously I got what I wanted). Shouldn't it be giving parallel maxima of several values?

Comment: Hi @CPak, sorry for the confusion and thanks for the solutions. I have modified my codes accordingly in my question following your answer. Thanks again!

Comment: Yeah, `pmax` is not necessary, you can use `max` I think.